# How to post Multipart Requests with Files in cakephp3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am facing trouble to post the files data in cakephp 3 using http client. Below is the code I am using.

Used to  form data at top of controller

```
use Cake\Http\Client\FormData;
```

Create object of `fromData` before submit form

```
$data = new FormData();
```

Collect the whole form data in array

```
$parametersArray = array(
    'parentTypeId'          => $userDetail->userTypeId,
    'parentId'              => $userDetail->userTypeId,
    'canChangeTrainingPlan' => false,
    'userObject' => array(
        'userTypeId'        => $this->request->data['user_type'],
        'userProfile' => array(
            'firstName'     => $this->request->data['first_name'],
            'lastName'      => $this->request->data['last_name'],
            'dateOfBirth'   => $this->request->data['user_dob'],
            'email'         => $this->request->data['user_email'],
            'phone'         => $this->request->data['user_phone'],
            'profileImage'  => $this->request->data['imageFile']['name'],
            'houseNumber'   => $this->request->data['house_number'],
            'streetNumber'  => $this->request->data['street_number'],
            'locality'      => $this->request->data['user_localty'],
            'landmark'      => $this->request->data['user_landmark'],
            'city'          => $this->request->data['user_city'],
            'state'         => $this->request->data['user_state'],
            'country'       => $this->request->data['user_country'],
            'pincode'       => $this->request->data['user_type'],
        )
    )
);
```

Create the final array for the post in third party API

```
$finalArray = array(
    'imageFile'  => $this->request->data['imageFile']['name'],
    'postData'   => json_encode($parametersArray),
);
```

Add data array to formData

```
$data->add($parametersArray);
```

Now use the Add file code as mentioned in documentation
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html

```
// This will append the file to the form data as well.
$file = $data->addFile('imageFile', $this->request->data['imageFile']);
$file->contentId($this->request->data['imageFile']['name']);
$file->disposition('attachment');

// Send the request.
$response = $http->post(
    BASE_API_URL.'user/register/'.$userDetail->id,
    $data,
    ['headers' => ['Content-Type' => $data->contentType()]]
);
```

Now the problem is that I am getting few warning of `file_get_contents()` and Response 400 Bad Request from API.
API is working fine tested it using postman.

**API required Input , output and Response**

```
URL:    {BASE_URL}/user/register/{currentUserId}    
Input:  {currentUserId} the logged in user id
    Form Data with following params:    
    imageFile   the user profile image file selected from PC
    postData    "{
""parentTypeId"":1,
""parentId"":1,
""canChangeTrainingPlan"":false,
""userObject"":{""id"":5,""userTypeId"":3,""userProfile"":{""firstName"":""Jyotsana"",""lastName"":""Arora"",""dateOfBirth"":""1989-07-16"",""email"":""arorajyotsana0@gmail.com"",""phone"":"""",""profileImage"":""<FILE_NAME>"",""houseNumber"":"""",""streetNumber"":"""",""locality"":"""",""landmark"":"""",""city"":"""",""state"":"""",""country"":"""",""pincode"":""160022""}}}
""profileImage"" key must contain the selected File name"
API Params  API must have following parameters: 
    enctype:    multipart/form-data'
    contentType:    false
    processData:    false
    cache:  false
Output:     "User object with complete details:
USER_ID > 0 : Successful Registration
USER_ID = 0 : Current user is not allowed to register this user
USER_ID = -1: Server Error
USER_ID = -2: Current User Id is invalid
USER_ID = -3: Input User object is not correct
USER_ID = -4: Email already exists
USER_ID = -8: Parent Id is invalid"
```

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP - thanks!

Comment: I think you should add data type `$data->type('image/jpeg');`  when creating the data object.

Answer (score 2):

You've misread the documentation, you cannot pass file upload arrays, neither to `HttpClient::post()`, nor to `FormData::addFile()`. The examples showing how user data is being passed from the request, just demonstrates how to sanely do that, given that strings prepended with an `@` will be interpreted as local/remote file inclusion paths (which is why it's mentioned in hat section).

Long story short, `FormData::addFile()` only accepts file resource handles, or file inclusion paths prepended with an `@` (which is deprecated however as noted in the red warning box). So, as shown in the first example in the docs, passing a file handle should fix the problem with regards to invalid form data being generated.

```
$file = $data->addFile(
    'imageFile',
    fopen($this->request->data['imageFile']['tmp_name'], 'r')
);
```

Also you should explicitly convert the data to a string as shown in the example:

```
$response = $http->post(
    BASE_API_URL.'user/register/'.$userDetail->id,
    (string)$data, // <<< cast data to a string
    ['headers' => ['Content-Type' => $data->contentType()]]
);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Http Client > Building Multipart Request Bodies by Hand](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#building-multipart-request-bodies-by-hand)**
- **[API > \Cake\Http\Client\FormData::addFile()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Http.Client.FormData.html#_addFile)**

Comment: how to add multiple headers in the request ?

Comment: @abhilash.r Please try to avoid asking unrelated questions in the comments. For such quick questions you're best of asking on IRC or Slack. That being said, as you can see in the example, the `headers` option is an array, so simply add more header entries to that array.